# PDO statement, quotes are stored as?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, escaping, php-7.2

So, I'm really new to **PDO**, and I was trying some stuff and practicing it, and happens that I became really confuse about what is happening to my database once I'm trying to insert some special characters with this code below:

```
<?php
    $post_cat     = 4;
    $post_title   = "TESTING";
    $post_author  = "Test";
    $post_image   = "test_image.png";
    $post_content = "“Luo Changan, I grant you five breaths’ time. Show me whether you’re actually such a ‘person’ as you say, or a dog that would ‘beg to surrender!’”";
    $post_tags    = "novel, mga, chinese novel";
    $ID_post_stat = 2;

    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:charset=utf8mb4;hostname=localhost;dbname=cms;", "root", "");
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO posts (ID_post_category, post_title, post_author, post_image, post_content, post_tags, ID_post_status) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');

    $stmt->bindParam(1, $post_cat);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $post_title);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $post_author);
    $stmt->bindParam(4, $post_image);
    $stmt->bindParam(5, $post_content);
    $stmt->bindParam(6, $post_tags);
    $stmt->bindParam(7, $ID_post_stat);
    $stmt->execute();

    /* data stored:   

    +------------------+------------+-------------+----------------+-----------------------------------------+---------------------------+----------------+
    | ID_post_category | post_title | post_author | post_image     | post_content                            | post_tags                 | ID_post_status |
    +------------------+------------+-------------+----------------+-----------------------------------------+---------------------------+----------------+
    |                4 | TESTING    | Test        | test_image.png | ?Luo Changan, I grant you five breaths? | novel, mga, chinese novel |              2 |
    |                  |            |             |                | time. Show me whether you?re actually   |                           |                |
    |                  |            |             |                | such a ?person? as you say, or a dog    |                           |                |
    |                  |            |             |                | that would ?beg to surrender!??         |                           |                |
    +------------------+------------+-------------+----------------+-----------------------------------------+---------------------------+----------------+
    */
?>
```

I was looking for answers for **why** this characters (**“ ‘ ’ ”**) are not being stored on database and are replaced with (**?**) instead, I had tried to change the table and column to UTF8 as I had read some answers from the community, but it don't seems to make difference, its working fine with (áéíóú) though. Thanks in advance!

---

as suggested by Madhur Bhaiya, I had tried again to check on it charset, even aplied `charset=utf8mb4` to my PDO DSN what helped me alot instead of using `utf8_decode` or `utf8_encode` to each string, and it is indeed all set to UTF8 already, so I guess that this kind of characters like curly quotes aren't supported for this charset, then how can I solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: What you have is a currly quote, from something like MsWord.  Probably `Windows-1252` instead of `UTF8`

Comment: “ is a UTF-8 character. I built a [PDO container](https://github.com/Jaquarh/PDOEasy) for anyone to use that has everything configured already.